# How to get parameter from URL in DOJO2

Tags: dojo2

I have a URL: http://app/material/id/58

I want to get the id '58' on another widget but I am not able to splice the value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Answer (score 0):

> Dojo 2 Widgets can then be configured with these outlet identifiers
>   using the Outlet higher order component. Outlet returns a new widget
>   that can be used like any other widget within a render method, e.g.
>   w(MyFooOutlet, { })

**Map Parameters**:

When a widget is configured for an outlet it is possible to provide a callback function that is used to inject properties that will be available during render lifecycle of the widget.

```
mapParams(type: 'error | index | main', location: string, params: {[key: string]: any}, router: Router)
```

The following example uses mapParams to inject an **onClose** function that will go to the route registered against the other-outlet route and **id** property extracted from params in the MyViewWidget properties:

```
const mapParams = (options: MapParamsOptions) {
    const { type, params, router } = options;

    return {
        onClose() {
            // This creates a link for another outlet and sets the path
            router.setPath(router.link('other-outlet'));
        },
        id: params.id
    }
}

const FooOutlet = Outlet(MyViewWidget, 'foo', { mapParams });
```